# Idea on access/refresh token management

Tags: security, cookies, jwt, access-token, webapi

I have a web API which uses JWT tokens for accessing resources. Tokens are generated and sent to the client upon a successful authentication. A client uses them to access API's resource by attaching with each request using a specific header (Bearer). A somewhat standard practice.

But in my case it is also required to "forget" the token right after exiting/closing the app (a specific security measure).

One of issues with this is how a client (a web app in my case) stores the tokens. Basically there are two options:

1. `http-only`, `session` cookie which expires right away when closing the window;
2. session storage.

The issue with (1) is that it's not cleared when a browser's tab is closed but only when all the windows are.
And (2) is not secure since if an attacker manages to inject a code into a client he will be able to extract the access token.

As a workaround some tend to minimize a lifetime of an access token and use refresh tokens. And on top of that create a refresh token reuse detection and other stuff.

Another possible solution would be to use a specific BFF which authenticates with an API on behalf of a client (works like a proxy in this case), stores the access tokens inaccessible for an attacker and provides a client with just a cookie which holds another "token". But that doesn't solve the problem with tab closing which is required and also adds more complexity and another project to support (not mentioning a delay).

But I thought of some combination of both approaches.

The token is a JWT kind which consists of a `header`, `payload` and a `signature`. What if an API would split this token in 2 parts: `header`+`payload` for a `http-only`, `session` cookie and `signature` for a client to include in a header?

A client would then send requests as usual including a "token" and also use a cookie with the rest of the JWT. A server upon receiving a request would just concatenate both parts and work with that.

This solves both cases:

1. the relevant part of the token is stored securely in a `http-only` cookie and inaccessible for JS (i.e. secure);
2. a signature will be lost when a tab is closed and so the cookie along would be unusable (i.e. a token is "forgotten" when closing a tab).

What do you guys think about it? Is it a usable pattern? Did anyone used something like this before? Perhaps there are some issues with this approach?

Of course this could be used together with refresh tokens and some other patterns.

Comment: Friends do not let friends implement their own authentication. If the business requirements go against common practice and supported solutions, they must be changed. Just as good you may come up with an idea of designing your own browser that will behave and treat cookies/local storage the way you would like them to be treated. In fact there may be a browser like this already. Make your users run the app in some incognito window. The session will be deleted on when browser closed.

Comment: @MarekPuchalski I'm not sure this is feasible. I'm not aware of any methods which would force incognito mode.

Answer (score 1):

**CLARIFYING REQUIREMENTS**

The `requirement` is interesting, since technically discarding a cookie feels like a `solution`. The requirement might be better expressed like this:

- When a browser tab is closed, it must not be possible for its API credential to be abused by malicious sites.

As a default and mainstream solution I would use a BFF that issues short lived access tokens in HTTP only cookies that expire `soon` after a browser tab is closed. These should also use the `SameSite=strict` property, for the best protection against cookie misuse via cross site request forgery.

**SPLIT TOKENS**

Your suggestion is interesting though, and valid solutions of this type exist. I work at Curity where [this article of ours on the split token pattern](https://curity.io/resources/learn/split-token-pattern/) is one possible related API approach for receiving tokens.

**DESIGNING A SOLUTION**

Your suggestion has some validity, but security is often a trade off with other factors, and there are these downsides:

- Non standard API client security, that uses multiple HTTP headers and is more complex plus harder to explain.
- Works against the default multi-tab browsing capability, and users would likely consider the behavior to have poor usability. Note also that multi-tab browsing would require the signature part to be stored in local storage, not session storage.
- Non standard API security, though one option for preventing this is to use an API gateway to recompose the JWT access token when required before forwarding it to APIs. Doing so would enable non-browser clients to call the API in the standard way.

Sometimes stakeholders such as product owners or architects raise this type of `requirement` via sweeping statements. This can result in unexpected costs and complexities. So if applicable, perhaps discuss the pros and cons I have raised with them, before finalising your design.

Comment: Thanks for the article. Will study it. As for the requirement, the data is quite sensitive, hence such security measures. Regarding BFF usage, it adds some complexity (creating, maintaining, deploying, etc.). We didn't want to introduce another service in this chain. As for cons: multi-tabbing is already implemented through session storage sharing using browser events. And thanks for the idea of an API gateway "token concatenation" function. Could be useful and we can even use a simple reverse proxy for this.